Setting keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot using flameshot does not work: how to fix?
so I have this custom keyboard shortcut but it does not trigger flameshot. Any ideas what could be wrong?
things I tried:

I tried running "/usr/bin/flameshot gui" on the terminal and that works fine.
I tried other key combos and they don't do anything.

Thanks


Does this Flameshot guide help answer your question?

your Keyboard shortcut should be sh -c '/usr/bin/flameshot gui'
